# Javascript Conditional return object

Tags: javascript

I used [aws-sns](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/?whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc) to create one webhook. Two lambda functions are checked by this webhook. One of the lambda functions publishes 'orderId' and'startTime', while another publishes 'orderId' and 'roundName'. Both lambdas fire at different times. As a result, publishing can happen at two different times. One or both of the'startTime' and 'roundName' parameters may be undefined.

If 'roundName' exists, the 'updateOrder' variable will return 'roundName,' and the database will be updated. When'startTime' is set and 'roundName' is left blank, the 'roundName' will be rewritten from the database, which I don't want. Because if there is a 'roundName,' there will always be a 'roundName,' the value of 'roundName' can change but it will never be `undefined`.If `startTime` changes as well as `roundName` change then it will update the database. But my current logic is wrong. Struggling to implementing diffrent scenario logic.

```js
const data = {
  Records: [
    {
      Sns: {
        Message:
          '[{\n "orderId": "a4013438-926f-4fdc-8f6a-a7aa402b40ea",\n "roundName": "RO1"}]',
      },
    },
  ],
};
const existingData = [
  {
    modifiedAt: "2022-03-09T13:18:06.211Z",
    lastMile: "progress",
    createdAt: "2022-02-26T06:38:50.967+00:00",
    orderId: "a4013438-926f-4fdc-8f6a-a7aa402b40ea",
  },
];

// parse the data
const parseData = data.Records.flatMap((record) =>
  JSON.parse(record.Sns.Message)
);

// check if the data exist or not
const existingOrder = existingData.filter(
  (o1) => parseData.some((o2) => o1.orderId === o2.orderId)
);

// if there is no existingOrder then return false
if (existingOrder.length === 0) return;

// if there is exisiting order then add roundName and startTime from SNS event
const updateOrder = existingOrder.map((i) => {
  const roundName = parseData.find((r) => {
    return r.orderId === i.orderId;
  }).roundName;
  const startTime = parseData.find((r) => {
    return r.orderId === i.orderId;
  }).startTime;

  return {
    roundName: roundName ?? "",
    startTime: startTime ?? "",
  };
});

console.log(updateOrder);
```

Comment: what is your expected result? I am getting this `[ { roundName: 'RO1', startTime: '' } ]`

Comment: First of all did you understand my question :D. Because my english is not good. I got the expected result. When startTime has value and roundName does not have value then it will will rewrite the roundName as an empty string.

Comment: you mean you fixed your code already? which means you don't want my help ?

Comment: Nope You understand wrong.  Think about this scenario, first lambda trigger which has `orderId` and `roundName`. When there is `roundName` it store in the database as an updated the order table with same orderId.  Second lambda trigger where there is same `orderId` but this time `startTime` has value and `roundName` does not have value. If you check updateOrder, you  will see conditional syntax. if there is `roundName` return empty string. which wrong because it had value from the first lambda and stored it in the order table

Comment: it has nothing do with your lambda gets triggered twice the code uses javascript and it has a map and filter, you have message which has json embedded into it, you are doing a parse, what you get it will parse, if the database has values then it should have come inside the message